# ASP Core 2.1 Model Binder and Passing Colleciton Not Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have looked at several other posts and tried implementing their solutions but they do not seem to be working :/

I have an action with 3 params:

```cs
public async Task<something> Post([FromBody]dynamic param1, [FromQuery]int[] param2, [FromQuery]string param3)
```

```cs
public async Task<something> Post([FromBody]dynamic param1, [FromQuery]List<int> param2, [FromQuery]string param3)
```

http request: http://localhost:8080/api/someResource?param1=testValue&param2=0&param2=1&param2=2&param2=34

body (json): {"test":123}

> Param1 and param3 are bound as expected, but param2 is either always
>   null (if collection) or int[0] (if array).
>
> ModelState indicates no errors. However, if I manually inspect the
>   context: HttpContext.Request.Query["param2"][0],
>   HttpContext.Request.Query["param2"][1], etc. I can get the values this
>   way. Another post mentioned they just sent a comma-separated
>   collection and .Split them, but I would prefer to use the model binder
>   if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MatějŠtágl You are wrong. By asp.net design, you can add values to a list by calling the property multiple times in the query string, each time represent a new entry in the list

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I did that... the example string I posted does exactly that. Mind showing me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two ways to solve the problem :

1. Change your action code as below :

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<something> Post([FromBody]dynamic param1, [FromQuery(Name ="param2")]int[] param2, [FromQuery]string param3) {
       // ////
   }
   ```

then you can send the request as above .

2. Send the QueryString by appending a index `[]` for every element in param2:

```js
POST /yourpath/?param1=testValue&param2[0]=0&param2[1]=1&param2[2]=2&param2[3]=34 HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type : application/json

{"test":123}
```

Both should work as expected .

Comment: that actually worked! I had to include (Name ="param2") for the array to bind. Using the querystring '/yourpath/?param1=testValue&param2[0]=0&param2[1]=1&param2[2]=2&param2[3]=34' would not work without adding (Name ="param2") to the action parameter. Thanks @itminus

I also used  '/yourpath/?param1=testValue&param2=0&param2=1&param2=2&param2=34' and it worked as well, but only if the action parameter had (name="param2"). I wish I understood why the binder is having issues or if that is expected. At any rate, thanks again for the help!